# Get GCC to use AVX in 32-bit code (-m32)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-optimization, avx

I have a C program that must run only on Ivy Bridge CPU where I'm compiling the code, on gcc 4.8 I have tried to compile using `-march=native` to take advantage of all specific instruction of the CPU.
I want to compile this also in 32-bit mode for some research comparisons

I have compiled the program in this way for x64 (note I'm on Linux x64)

```
gcc -march=native -s -O2 mycode.c
```

and disassembling the code, I can see that AVX instruction set is used

And in this way for 32-bit x86

```
gcc -m32 -march=native -s -O2 mycode.c
```

If I try to disassemble the code I don't see any AVX instruction, and the instruction set is Pentium Pro, 80x87.  Like `fld` / `fadd` / `fstp` for FP math.  Adding `-mavx` doesn't help, same result.

How could I fix this?

Comment: `-mavx` doesn't tell the compiler it _must_ use AVX instructions, only that it can do if it wants to ... but maybe it decides that using them would not produce better code

Comment: @JonathanWakely I know but seems pretty strange that the same program compiled for x64 takes advantage of AVX while in x86 prefer avoid at all the use of these. (In addition the generated code is way longer in x86 without new istruction set.)

Comment: gcc might "think" that the 32 bit OS's (and 64-bit OS 32-bit emulation) don't have 256-bit YMM state support. -mavx should have enable the optimization though.

Comment: It's common for people to simply not care about 32-bit anymore. "If you want performance, upgrade to 64-bit. Then we can talk." Even Intel is showing a bit of this since AVX512 will stick to 8 registers on 32-bit but will get a 32 registers on 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GCC 4.8.3 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options):

> -m32
>   -m64
>   -mx32
>
> Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The -m32 option sets int, long, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code that runs on any i386 system.
>   The -m64 option sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer types to 64 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture. For Darwin only the -m64 option also turns off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic options.
>
> The -mx32 option sets int, long, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture.

The closest you're going to get to `-m32` with AVX instructions is using `-mx32` in it's place , but it might not be what you want.

Comment: yes with -mx32 seems use also AVX istruction but the generated assembly when I try to decompile for some reason is a total disaster barely readable. If I compile for x64 or with -m32 is readable in both cases

Answer (score 0):

The default for `-m32` is `-mfpmath=387`.

GCC4.8 *will* auto-vectorize with AVX if you compile with `-O3 -m32 -march=native`, but to get scalar AVX math like `vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [edx+eax*4]`, **use `-mfpmath=sse`** as well

e.g.

```
void foo(float *arr){
    for(int i=0;i<4096;i++){
        arr[i] *= 2;
    }
}
```

compiles [on Godbolt with gcc4.8.5](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+foo(float+*arr)%7B%0A++++for(int+i%3D0%3Bi%3C4096%3Bi%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++arr%5Bi%5D+*%3D+2%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g485,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-m32++-mfpmath%3Dsse+-O2++-Wall+-march%3Dnative',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.8.5+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g485,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-m32+-O2++-Wall+-march%3Dnative',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.8.5+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) `-m32 -O2  -Wall -march=native` (on a Skylake-X) to this:

```
foo(float*):
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
    xor     eax, eax
.L3:
    fld     DWORD PTR [edx+eax*4]
    fadd    st, st(0)
    fstp    DWORD PTR [edx+eax*4]
    add     eax, 1
    cmp     eax, 4096
    jne     .L3
    rep ret
```

At `-O3` it uses x87 for the scalar intro/cleanup, but still `vaddps ymm` for the main loop.

Or with **`-mfpmath=sse`** `-m32 -O2  -Wall -march=native` we get what you probably expected:

```
foo(float*):
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
        xor     eax, eax
.L3:
        vmovss  xmm0, DWORD PTR [edx+eax*4]
        vaddss  xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        vmovss  DWORD PTR [edx+eax*4], xmm0
        add     eax, 1
        cmp     eax, 4096
        jne     .L3
        rep ret
```

I used `-march=native` because gcc4.8.5 is too old for `-march=ivybridge`, and I didn't want to suggest `-march=corei7-avx` or whatever stupid name they used to use.  And definitely didn't want to suggest just `-mavx` which enables AVX without setting tuning options, leaving it at `-mtune=generic`.  And fails to enable popcnt, BMI, or whatever else your CPU might have.

---

BTW, `-o2` sets the output filename to `2`.  And `-s` makes a stripped binary, hardly what you want for disassembling.